# graduate admissions - Can I apply again in March for the same intake after being rejected in December?

Tags: graduate-admissions

This is a hypothetical question pertaining to the entry of Fall'19. Suppose I apply in December and get rejected. By next semester, I predict my grades would have improved a lot, crossing me over past the 7pt grade line out of 10, which a substantial thing. Additionally, by January I will be involved in a research project which will definitely give me brownie points. Given that I think my application's strength will improve, would it be allowed to apply again? Will my application be considered afresh in March?

Or, should I just wait till March and apply? I hear that intake chances are higher in December, since there are more seats to be filled.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to be a bit easier to read? For example, "sem" and "Jan" is a bit unnecessary. You also haven't even stated what you're applying for, or which country. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying for an equation containing two incommensurate things. It is an impossible task without a lot of statistical research. You will just need to make a decision. Check the university's rules, however, to see if rejection comes with a prohibition to re-apply without at least a substantial wait. Such rules should be public knowledge and easy to obtain from admissions officials or web-sites.